# How do I use Add-Type to load Microsoft.Web.Deployment?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, msdeploy

I am writing some PowerShell scripts that use the [MSDeploy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.deployment.workflow.activities.msdeploy.aspx) API. I can load the assembly using

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Web.Deployment")
```

The location is in the [GAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache):

```
PS > [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Web.Deployment") | fl Location

Location : C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Web.Deployment\7.1.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Web.Deployment.dll
```

However, I am not able to load the assembly using [Add-Type](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849914.aspx). I get an error saying the assembly cannot be found and that one or more assemblies are missing.

```
PS > Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Web.Deployment
Add-Type : Cannot add type. The assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Deployment' could not be found.
At line:1 char:9
+ Add-Type <<<<  -AssemblyName Microsoft.Web.Deployment
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Web.Deployment:String) [Add-Type], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ASSEMBLY_NOT_FOUND,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand

Add-Type : Cannot add type. One or more required assemblies are missing.
At line:1 char:9
+ Add-Type <<<<  -AssemblyName Microsoft.Web.Deployment
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-Type], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ASSEMBLY_LOAD_ERRORS,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand
```

How can I use Add-Type to load Microsoft.Web.Deployment?

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

PowerShell only allows a certain pre-defined set of assemblies to be loaded by their partial/simple name. You're going to need to load it via its fully qualified name, for example:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName ('Microsoft.Web.Deployment, Version=7.1.0.0, ' +
                        'Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35')
```

Comment: whyyyyyyy? i dont know how often i want to do this. would be so easy if there was just a `add-type -gac microsoft.some.assembly` that loads the latest version like we do for visual studio.

Comment: You can always load by path `Add-Type -Path C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_64\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll`

Comment: yeah but that's annoying and you have to go find the path and stuff. it would be easy for me to create a function to automatically do this and put it in my profile but im kinda surprised microsoft hasnt done this. oh well maybe next version. maybe i should suggest it to them somewhere