# System.Collections.Generic Fully Qualified Name

Tags: powershell

What is the fully qualified name for the assembly where System.Collections.Generic is stored?

I have this code:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.XML.Linq"
Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Collections.Generic"
```

Linq gets added fine, however I get this error for System.Collections.Generic:

```
Add-Type : Cannot add type. The assembly 'System.Collections.Generic' could not be found.
```

[How do I use Add-Type to load Microsoft.Web.Deployment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621900/how-do-i-use-add-type-to-load-microsoft-web-deployment) says to use the fully qualified name, eg:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName ('Microsoft.Web.Deployment, Version=7.1.0.0, ' +
                        'Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35')
```

How can I find out what the fully qualified name is?

Answer (score 2):

The types in the namespace `System.Collections.Generic` are mostly in mscorlib.dll which is automatically loaded into PowerShell.  You don't need to Add-Type to use most generic collections.  You should check the specific collection type you want to use to make sure.  [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is provided by mscorlib.dll.

To find out the fully qualified name, use the MSDN docs to find out what assembly contains the type.  Then look under C:\windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL in PowerShell. Find the assembly by name and the subdir will list the version and the pubkey token.

Comment: What if I need to run the script on different computers?
Will the pubkey token be different?

Comment: I can see that C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL has no folder for System.Collections.Generic.
Do I need to download this library?

Comment: You're missing the step of looking up the namespace of interest on Bing or Google. Pick the type you are using - say Dictionary<T,V>.  That link is above in my answer.  Right towards the top of the topic it will say "Assembly:" and will indicate which assembly the type is in.  If it is mscorlib.dll, System.dll or System.Core.dll you do not have to do anything as those assemblies will always be loaded by PowerShell.

Comment: I just got confused because all the other folders were System namespaces.