# How do I reference an assembly from the GAC in a PowerShell module?

Tags: powershell, gac

I'm writing a PowerShell module which depending on the SMO assemblies in SQL Server. (The only one I need to reference is Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll)

When I've been developing module. I've just taken a copy of the assembly I need and referenced it in my manifest file similar to this:

```
RequiredAssemblies = @(         
    "$env:userprofile\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Dependencies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll"
)
```

I would assume that in a production environment you'd want to reference assemblies from a standard location. I'd assume a standard location would be the GAC.

If I reference the assembly from the GAC, I get this, but this looks like it could break if a new version of the assembly is installed:

```
RequiredAssemblies = @(
    'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\gac_msil\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo\12.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll'
)
```

I could also reference the assembly directly from the SDK:

```
RequiredAssemblies = @(
    'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll'
)
```

Another option I've considered (but possibly might be breaking a EULA somewhere) is to copy the assemblies to a server share and reference that like so:

```
RequiredAssemblies = @(
    '\\MyServer\PowerShellDependencies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll'
)
```

But how should I be doing this?

If it's relevant, all computers that this module will be installed on are 64-bit and will have the SMO libraries installed. Also, this isn't a publicly available piece of software, it's being deployed on a company network.

**Update:** I've tried only specifying the name of the assembly in the manifest and this appears to work.

```
RequiredAssemblies = @(
    'Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll'
)
```

Comment: Will the SMO objects be available in the GAC already, or will you install them?

Comment: @RichRousseau, I'm trying to see if it's legal to bundle the .dll files with the module, otherwise yes, they'd have to be preinstalled first.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you're going to deploy the SMO assemblies as private assemblies, then I wouldn't recommend loading them from direct references.

To load from the GAC, use the Add-Type cmdlet with the fully qualified assembly name...

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"
```

Related:
[How do I use Add-Type to load Microsoft.Web.Deployment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621900/how-do-i-use-add-type-to-load-microsoft-web-deployment)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'private assemblies'?

Comment: Any assembly not in the GAC, so any custom assemblies you build and deploy with your applications or any 3rd party assemblies not registered in the GAC that you'll be deploying with your application.

Comment: Well technically the assemblies I need aren't custom since they're part of a Microsoft technology. If I'm legally allowed to redistribute the assemblies with the module then everyone is happy. I'm just trying to find something that tells me if I can do that without violating any EULA's.

Comment: For anyone trying to find out the version and PublicKey for an assembly,  go to C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\<My.Assumbly.Name> and you will see a folder with a name in the form of <Version>__<PublicKey>. Take the assembly name, version, and public key bits and substitute them into the string above and your good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can also specify just the assembly without the version info:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Xml.Linq"
```